# How to mimic Finder/Mac OS duplication in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an interesting problem where I am trying to implement a ruby duplication mechanism similar to MAC OS Finder. I need to try to do the following. I have a ruby object with the following fields:

```
 song.title = 'RocketMan'
 song.slug = 'rocket-man'
```

With the help of [Mongoid Slug](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid-slug), if I were to `.clone` the above object I would get the following below. The slug is set by mongoid-slug gem functionality.

```
 song.title = 'RocketMan'
 song.slug = 'rocket-man-1'
```

What I'm having trouble is trying to implement a Mac type duplication mechanism where I would mimic the following algorithm below. What is important to note with MAC OS Finder is that whichever file I were to duplicate produces the next increment.

```
file.jpg
file copy.jpg
file copy 1.jpg
file copy 2.jpg
```

So if I were to duplicate any of the files above, the proceeding file would be file copy 3.jpg

Now for the problem, I am essentially, trying to duplicate this with ruby.For the example below, please note the 'original object', it plays an important part in this problem.

```
##### ORIGINAL #####
song.title = 'RocketMan'
song.slug = 'rocket-man'

#.clone 

song.title = 'RocketMan'
song.slug = 'rocket-man-1'
```

If I were to `clone` the original ruby object, I get the following:

```
song.title = 'RocketMan'
song.slug = 'rocket-man-2'
```

If I were to `clone` the object with slug `rocket-man-1`, the following is produced.

```
song.title = 'RocketMan'
song.slug = 'rocket-man-1-1'
```

then if cloned again, I would get 'rocket-man-1-2' etc.

Is there some kind of gem or algorithm that I could potentially use to mimic the ability of MAC OS Finder? It seems to me that no matter what file or its copy I use to duplicate in mac os, I get the right increment. With ruby and mongoid-slug, if I wanted to mimic the Finder, I would have to only clone the original object. A user in this project I'm working on can clone the original and/or the clone. If they were to duplicate the copy, then the whole naming convention doesn't work.

If anyone has some insight I would greatly appreciate it. Also, just to clarify, the slug generation wouldn't matter. What Im most interested in is trying to create the following titles from copying:

```
Rocket Man
Rocket Man Copy
Rocket Man Copy 2
Rocket Man Copy 3
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for your feeback Stefan. Youre right, so I changed `Obect` to what it really represents which is a song. I hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expressions for matching the given title and generating the successor:

```
def next_title(title)
  case title
  when /(.*) Copy (\d*[1-9]\d*)\z/
    "#{$1} Copy #{$2.to_i.succ}"
  when /(.*) Copy\z/
    "#{$1} Copy 2"
  else
    "#{title} Copy"
  end
end

next_title("Rocket Man")         #=> "Rocket Man Copy"
next_title("Rocket Man Copy")    #=> "Rocket Man Copy 2"
next_title("Rocket Man Copy 2")  #=> "Rocket Man Copy 3"
```

It also handles several edge cases the way Finder does:

```
next_title("Rocket Man Copy 1")   #=> "Rocket Man Copy 2"
next_title("Rocket Man Copy 02")  #=> "Rocket Man Copy 3"
next_title("Rocket Man Copy 0")   #=> "Rocket Man Copy 0 Copy"
next_title("Rocket Man Copy -1")  #=> "Rocket Man Copy -1 Copy"
next_title("Copy")                #=> "Copy Copy"
next_title("Copy 2")              #=> "Copy 2 Copy"
```

To ensure unique titles, you have to call `next_title` repeatedly until you find one that doesn't already exist, e.g.:

```
title = "Rocket Man"
title = next_title(title) while Song.exists?(title: title)
```

Comment: Hey Stefan, thanks for your help but its not quite there yet. My solution that I've implemented is stuck on the same issue that yours has. This solution only works if you were to copy the next copy in succession. For example, with the above solution if I were to copy the original 'Rocket Man' song object I would get two 'Rocket Man Copy' objects. Instead of 'Rocket Man Copy' and Rocket Man Copy 2'. That's the tricky part that I am a bit stuck at.

Comment: @DanRubio in order to do so, you have to store the generated names somehow. Either in-memory or in a database.

Comment: Hey @Stefan by tweaking your code, I finally was able to get past my issue. Thanks for your assist, this helped me cross the finish line.